# Cannot figure out why JQuery UI datepicker is not setting correct date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

My code:

```
$('.trainingDateInput').datepicker("setDate", "01/06/2014");
```

With the code above calendar is not coming up at all. If I try this:

```
$('.trainingDateInput').datepicker({            
        dateFormat : 'mm-dd-yy',
        defaultDate: new Date()
    });
```

It works but does not match my date format m/d/yyyy, as soon as i change

```
dateFormat : 'mm-dd-yy',
```

to

```
dateFormat : 'm/d/yy',
```

DatePicker defaults to whatever date that input has. How do I set default date for the datepicker to bring up no matter what date input has?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly what you are saying, this is what you need:

```
$('input').datepicker({            
    dateFormat : 'm/d/yy'
}).datepicker("setDate", "01/06/2014");
```

You need the first `datepicker` call to initialize and create the datepicker. With the second one, you call `setDate` and override whatever the `input` originally had.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6LAVw/1/)

Comment: That worked as far as automatically inserting date into input. But my problem is that I have an input that get date from database and the date is 02/01/2006 and when i click on that input little datepicker calendar comes up and shows dates for the year 2006 and month February. How do I make that calendar to show current date when I click on that input with old date?